# Can't pairing with bluetooth speaker by using bluez-simple-agent

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to use bluetooth speaker from Raspberry Pi.

`hcitool scan` shows the device.

```
$ hcitool scan
Scanning ...
    xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx   MEOSOUND003
    xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx   macbook
```

And `l2ping` is ok.

```
$ sudo l2ping -c 1 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Ping: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (data size 44) ...
16 bytes from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx id 0 time 14.97ms
1 sent, 1 received, 0% loss
```

But it fails to make paring raspberry pi with the speaker.

```
$ bluez-simple-agent hci0 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.1:/: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.11" (uid=1000 pid=3715 comm="/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/bluez-simple-agent hci0 0") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable" member="Introspect" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.1" (uid=0 pid=2254 comm="/usr/sbin/bluetoothd ")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/bluez-simple-agent", line 102, in <module>
    path = manager.FindAdapter(args[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.11" (uid=1000 pid=3715 comm="/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/bluez-simple-agent hci0 0") interface="org.bluez.Manager" member="FindAdapter" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.1" (uid=0 pid=2254 comm="/usr/sbin/bluetoothd ")
```

How can I solve this problem?

### bluetooth.conf

Thanks for @AlanAu it found out I have to configure `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/bluetooth.conf`. But I couldn't figure out how to enable the bluetooth speaker.

The line `<allow send_type="method_call"></allow>` is what I added.

```
<!-- This configuration file specifies the required security policies
     for Bluetooth core daemon to work. -->

<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
<busconfig>

  <!-- ../system.conf have denied everything, so we just punch some holes -->

  <policy user="root">
    <allow own="org.bluez"/>
    <allow send_destination="org.bluez"/>
    <allow send_type="method_call"></allow>

    <!-- allow root to send to agents -->
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.Agent"/>

        <allow send_interface="org.bluez.HandsfreeAgent"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.MediaEndpoint"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.MediaPlayer"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.Watcher"/>
    <allow send_interface="org.bluez.ThermometerWatcher"/>
  </policy>

  <!-- allow users at the console, see consolekit or libpam-foreground -->
  <policy at_console="true">
    <allow send_destination="org.bluez"/>
  </policy>

  <!-- allow users of bluetooth group to communicate with hcid -->
  <policy group="bluetooth">
    <allow send_destination="org.bluez"/>
  </policy>

  <!-- allow users of lp group (printing subsystem) to communicate with hcid -->
  <policy group="lp">
    <allow send_destination="org.bluez"/>
  </policy>


  <policy context="default">
    <deny send_destination="org.bluez"/>
  </policy>

</busconfig>
```

I got following error after bluetooth server restared:

```
$ bluez-simple-agent hci0 00:25:DB:96:09:5E
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.1:/: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.45" (uid=1000 pid=5079 comm="/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/bluez-simple-agent hci0 0") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable" member="Introspect" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.1" (uid=0 pid=2254 comm="/usr/sbin/bluetoothd ")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/bluez-simple-agent", line 102, in <module>
    path = manager.FindAdapter(args[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.45" (uid=1000 pid=5079 comm="/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/bluez-simple-agent hci0 0") interface="org.bluez.Manager" member="FindAdapter" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.1" (uid=0 pid=2254 comm="/usr/sbin/bluetoothd ")
```

And this is with `sudo`:

```
$ sudo bluez-simple-agent hci0 00:25:DB:96:09:5E
Creating device failed: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationRejected: Authentication Rejected
```

### with NoInputNotput option

```
$ bluez-simple-agent -c NoInputNoOutput hci0 00:25:DB:96:09:5E
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.1:/: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.52" (uid=1000 pid=5218 comm="/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/bluez-simple-agent -c NoI") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable" member="Introspect" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.1" (uid=0 pid=2254 comm="/usr/sbin/bluetoothd ")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/bluez-simple-agent", line 102, in <module>
    path = manager.FindAdapter(args[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.52" (uid=1000 pid=5218 comm="/usr/bin/python /usr/bin/bluez-simple-agent -c NoI") interface="org.bluez.Manager" member="FindAdapter" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.1" (uid=0 pid=2254 comm="/usr/sbin/bluetoothd ")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a dbus permissions problem. The bluetooth.conf dbus file should have been installed that sets up correct bluetooth dbus permissions. Check that you have this dbus config file and that it contains the right policies: /etc/dbus-1/system.d/bluetooth.conf

Comment: Thanks for your advice! But I couldn't find out what value should I set to enable the paring. Where can I get the information of it?

Comment: Please give the exact problem after you fixed up bluetooth.conf.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the put the error messages. I just put to my question.

Comment: There could be several causes of that. It's hard to say without access to the particular speaker you have. But try this: bluez-simple-agent -c NoInputNoOutput hci0 00:25:DB:96:09:5E

Comment: With `sudo` it worked! I don't know how to handle the device though, I'll try with it. Thanks!